# rdiff-backup fails when deleting files from backup directory

Tags: backup, rdiff-backup

In my search for a reliable backup program i have come across rdiff-backup which seems like a good solution for me. To test it a little bit i did the following:

- Create a directory a
- Add three files to it (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg)
- Create a directory b
- Create a backup by running rdiff-backup a b
- Delete 3.jpg from directory b (let's assume accidental deletion, file corruption etc.)
- Run backup again using rdiff-backup a b

Ok so here i would expect rdiff-backup to detect that a file is missing, warn, backup it again. But it doesn't.

So let's see if we can make sure the backup is alright:

- Run rdiff-backup --verify b

This just hangs without giving any useful information even with -v 9

So my question is: Can you reproduce this ? If so, how the hell can this happen with a widely used backup tool ? This is the most basic thing i expect that the backup will detect that it no longer has a copy of a source file.

I really hope i'm simply overlooking something here...

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a problem in `rdiff-backup` and the worst part is that even if you notice it, it's not easy to fix. You need to either copy the file (`cp -a`) in the backup directory if it hasn't changed since the last backup or otherwise delete the reference to this file for the rdiff-backup metadata files in order to do the backup anew.

Comment: So with duplicity generating corrupt backups when a transfer is interrupted and rdiff-backup not noticing missing files what is everybody using ?